# Capistrano: bundler: failed to load command: rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, passenger, bundler

I am trying to deploy a Rails app from a Windows development machine to a Debian 9 VPS using Capistrano, Passenger, and RVM. I got RVM and Passenger set up with Apache on the VPS and Capistrano set up on the Windows machine. However, when I try to run `cap production deploy`, I get the following error:

`bundler: failed to load command: rake (/var/www/APPNAME/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rake)`

One quirk of developing on Windows is that the `Gemfile.lock` must be edited on deployment to remove Windows-specific versions of gems. I have written a custom task to perform this action, which seems to run as expected.

Here are some files that might be useful:

- [log/capistrano.log, starting with the custom task](https://pastebin.com/tB49GX8j)
- [Gemfile](https://pastebin.com/XGYfxc6b)
- [Gemfile.lock](https://pastebin.com/NuEub8dD)
- [Capfile](https://pastebin.com/1mmpE2Dk)
- [config/deploy.rb](https://pastebin.com/t9AqynXE)
- [config/deploy/production.rb](https://pastebin.com/bFtvx89Y)
- [lib/capistrano/tasks/dewindowsify.rake (the custom task)](https://pastebin.com/3h3fdkzh)

Comment: have you checked if `/var/www/APPNAME/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rake` exists on the VPS? And is your capistrano ssh user in the rvm group? Does your capistrano setup source the rvm environment before trying to call ruby scripts?

Comment: I checked and the file exists. There is no group called "rvm" on the VPS; rvm is installed into the ssh user's home directory. I am using the capistrano-rvm gem and the source command is in the ssh user's bashrc, so I think the environment is being loaded.

Comment: I'd suggest testing that assumption, rvm is very fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved after I downgraded Bundler to version 1.12.5 (it was previously version 1.15.4). I assume there is some sort of conflict with my setup and newer versions of Bundler; but until the underlying issue is patched, I will continue using the older version.